# jQuery UI issues in Safari when zoomed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, safari

I've been experiencing a number of issues with pretty basic jQueryUI features in Safari
when some browser zooming is applied:

- A draggable element jumps as a second drag is initiated. [Observed on the official demo](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#default)
- A draggable with revert option jumps as it initiates revert. [Observed on the official demo](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#revert)
- A draggable element with snap to element option snap incorrectly position-wise once the elements have been dragged around. [Observed on the official demo](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#snap-to).

Versions:

- jQuery: 1.11.1
- Safari: 7.1

jQueryUI reacts fine to Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer 11 browser zooming. How could I get jQueryUI to react correctly with Safari's browser zoom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is caused by a bug in WebKit that is fixed in Chrome, but not in Safari:

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=105979

**Description**: getComputedStyle() returns scaled values for properties such as left, right, top and bottom (when the 'position' of an element is 'relative'). This makes it impossible to rely on these values.

Here is a test case provided in the bug report:

https://bug-105979-attachments.webkit.org/attachment.cgi?id=181121

It can be worked around by monkey-patching getComputedStyle. This is a rather aggressive approach and I would only advise to do this if the impact on your project is serious.

Here is a demonstration:

http://codepen.io/lampyridae/pen/PwZNdo

The fix itself:

```
//Monkey-patching getComputedStyle to work around the following 
//WebKit Safari bug:
//https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=105979
(function() {
   //tolerate small variations caused by zoom scaling
   var delta = 0.05;
   function close_enough(x, y) {
      var diff = x - y;
      return delta > diff && diff > -delta;
   }

   //Set up a reference element to measure
   //undesired variations from browser zooming
   var expected_left = 100;
   var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
   var ref_node = document.createElement("div");
   body.appendChild(ref_node);
   ref_node.style.position = "relative";
   ref_node.style.left = expected_left + "px";
   ref_node.style.height = "0";

   var native = window.getComputedStyle;

   window.getComputedStyle = function(elt) {
     //Bug only affects relative positioning.
     //Only intervene if the element is concerned.
     var styles = native(elt);
     if("relative" !== styles.position) {
        return styles;
     }

     //Measure undesired variation from reference element
     var ref_styles = native(ref_node);
     var ref_left = parseFloat(ref_styles.left);

     if(close_enough(expected_left, ref_left)) {
       return styles;
     }

     var proportion = ref_left / expected_left;

     //Copy styles
     //Use an object implementing the CSSStyleDeclaration interface.
     var cloned = document.createElement("div").style;
     var attr;
     for(var ii=0; ii < styles.length; ++ii){
       attr = styles[ii];
       cloned[attr] = styles[attr];
     }

     //correct styles
     var property_names = ["top", "right", "bottom", "left"];
     for(var ii = 0; ii < property_names.length; ++ii) {
         var prop_name = property_names[ii];
         if(prop_name in cloned) {
               cloned[prop_name] = (parseFloat(cloned[prop_name]) / proportion) + "px";
         }         
     }

     return cloned;
   }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

[A similar bug were reported 4 years ago](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6222) and was closed as it had been resolved by moving to Safari 5.

Unfortunately, zooming in webkit based browsers has some issues because of the way it is implemented, and this reflects in possible positioning errors when zooming. There is a proposal to unify this in a more consistent way, but no estimates when it could be implemented: http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/ScalesAndZooms

In the meantime I'm afraid there's only one thing you can do: refreshing the page after zooming will fix the positions of the elements.